# Error while run any flutter project in android platform class path error

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, build, classpath

**FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.**

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0.
> Required by:
> project :
> > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0.
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.pom'.
> > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                         4.4s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

Try to below methods:

Try to run **flutter clean** then **flutter pub get** then **flutter run** or run or your app OR if you use this commands the problem Is not work then go-to Android studio open adb select your device right click it and click on wipe Data or cold boot now and run your app

Comment: **No that's not working But thanks to response**

Comment: Ok try out this go to our project directory => android\app\build.gradle and change compileSdkVersion 28, minSdkVersion 21, targetSdkVersion 30 It solve your problem