# how to accepts certificates in android studio

Tags: flutter

Hi all my name is Vijay Rathwa and I am totally new in flutter and for programing and for coding language. please help me I am stuck in flutter. the error is below. please guide me step by step to solve the problem. Thank you

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
> platforms;android-30 Android SDK Platform 30
> build-tools;29.0.2 Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.2
> To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
> Alternatively, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

Using Android SDK: C:\Users\Wins\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 19s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: You should be referred my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/68507976/13997210 or you want to Android license try next command **flutter doctor --android-licenses**

Answer (score 0):

in flutter you should accept android sdk with this command

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

before that you should specify sdk on operation system environment

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check to ensure if the `Android SDK Platform-Tools` and `Android SDK Build Tools` are installed on your computer using `Android Studio`.

I faced the same issue some time ago, installing these tools using Android Studio helped me resolve the issue.
[image: Android Studio SDK Tools]